# How to match a particular number/field in CSV file consisting of only numbers separated by commas using regex?

Tags: regex, pcre, bbedit

I am using *BBEdit 12.6* to highlight certain numbers in different colors; to improve readability, in this regard,

Kindly help with a regex expression that would match no. `80 / 42 / 55` (8th field) in below sample file.

```
    10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100

    12,22,32,42,52,62,72,42,85,102

    15,25,35,45,55,65,75,55,65,105
```

As these are all numbers, I have used regex expressions to match the third number from end of line. but, its matching all three last number fields, not just one. this is not a search/replace operation, instead this pattern will be used in `.plist` file for color coding files using CLM https://www.barebones.com/support/develop/clm.html

the expression I have used, but problem is, it matches the final 3 number fields, not just one.

`(?x:(\d+,\d+)(?:,\d+$))`

a correct regex expression should match just the 8th field.

Comment: Try `\d+(?=(?:,\d+){2}$)` if you  need to match the 3rd numeric value from the end. Or, `^(?:\d+,){7}\K\d+` to match the eighth numeric field preceded with 7 numeric fields.

Comment: the first one \d+(?=(?:,\d+){2}$) worked. thanks a lot @Wiktor Stribiżew , I was sweating over it and you solved it like a charm. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may match 1+ digits that are followed with two occurrences of a comma and 1+ digits at the end of the line/string:

```
\d+(?=(?:,\d+){2}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xos7n9/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cd%2B(%3F%3D(%3F%3A%2C%5Cd%2B)%7B2%7D%24)):

[image]

**Details**

- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=(?:,\d+){2}$)`  - a positive lookahead (`(?=...)`) that matches a location immediately followed with two occurrences (`(?:...){2}`) of `,` and 1+ digits (`,\d+`) at the end of the string (`$`).